# How to Prevent Text and Table Breaks in PDF Creation using Puppeteer and AWS Lambda with Chromium

Tags: css, aws-lambda, puppeteer, pdf-generation, chromium-embedded

How can I ensure consistent styling and prevent text and table rows from breaking between pages while creating PDFs on AWS Lambda? The styling looks fine locally on my system, but when I run the same code on AWS Lambda, the PDF's styling gets distorted, and text and table rows are not rendering as expected, resulting in an unclear final PDF. I have already tried using various page-break properties, but the issue persists. Any ideas or solutions to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.